# JSON input for Upload function in WebApi C#

Tags: asp.net-web-api, rest-client

I have an upload function in my WebApi C# code, which works fine with Query string parameters. I will be passing the file in Rest client using multi-Form data and it works completely fine.

Now I have to change the parameters to JSON format, doing so the request is not hitting the controller. Can anyone please help me here.

```
public ReturnMsg UploadDocument(string fileName, string fileSize, string ApplNo, string DocId, string DocSize,string resumeId,string DependId)
    {
        ReturnMsg  objReturnMsg = new ReturnMsg ();
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        Stream stream = null;
        if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
            {
                var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                var filePath = string.Empty;
                stream = postedFile.InputStream;
            }
            objReturnMsg = Bll.UploadFiles(fileName, fileSize, DocId, DocSize,DependId,stream);
        }
        else
        {
            objReturnMsg.Status = "F";
            objReturnMsg.ReturnMessage = "Please Upload a Valid Form";
        }
        return objReturnMsg;
    }
```

I want it in

```
 public ReturnMsg UploadDocument(DocDetails docDet)
    {
        ReturnMsg objReturnMsg = new ReturnMsg ();
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        Stream stream = null;
        if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
            {
                var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                var filePath = string.Empty;
                stream = postedFile.InputStream;
            }
            objReturnMsg = Bll.UploadFiles(docDet.fileName, docDet.fileSize, docDet.DocId, docDet.DocSize,docDet.DependId,stream);
        }
        else
        {
            objReturnMsg.Status = "F";
            objReturnMsg.ReturnMessage = "Please Upload a Valid Form";
        }
        return objReturnMsg;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `[FromBody]` before DocDetails? I'm never quite sure when this is required, especially if this is a post request, but always worth suggesting!

Comment: Yes, I have tried adding [FromBody] and tried hitting the service from Rest Client. I passed the content-type as Multipart-Formdata and passed file part and text part with content-type application/json. It didnt work :(